# APP ID and APP secret for a Fan Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to view the appId and above all the app secret for a fan page which I'm an administrator?
I used to see this values in the developers/app section where I can see all my oldest pages but can't see this one that was the youngest. It was created 1 year ago.

Answer (score 2):

Fan pages do not have app Id and app secret, but apps do. You can view a list of all apps for which you are an admin or developer or tester at https://developers.facebook.com/apps. This page also has a search box which you can use to quick find in case you are owner of many apps.

Comment: but I'm admin only of 3 fan pages. In my app section I can see only 2 of them (and I can see the app ID and app secret) but I need the third, last, one.

Comment: Ialso tried to use the search box but there are no results with the name of the fanpage...

Comment: You should search with the name of the application, not with the name of the fan page. Also do you own the application? If not, who built it? perhaps a Vendor? Then they may be owning the app in which case you won't have access to the appid and secret.

Comment: how can i add existing fan page to facebook app?